# Azure Container Instance | Environment Variables from an Environment Variables File

Tags: azure, docker, environment-variables, azure-container-instances

How can I create an Azure container instance and configure it with an environment variables file?
Something that'd be equivalent to Docker's `--env-file` flag for the `run` command. I couldn't find a way to do that but I'm new to both Azure and Docker.

So it'd look something like: `az container create <...> --env-file myEnvFile` where `myEnvFile` is stored somewhere on Azure so I could grab it, like how Docker can grab such a file locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, from answers and my research, this is currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you want here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create

i.e.

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --environment-variables key1=value1 key2=value2
```

Apologies, realised you want it from a file, if running in a script can you not have the file set local environment variables or parse the file to set them and then run the command above?

Comment: Yes, it's possible - just wanted to know if it's possible without it (if Azure has some functionality that enables that - was hoping for just being able to use a flag).

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sure there is no parameter to set the environment variables of the Azure container instance from a file only through one command.

You can take a look at the parameter `--environment-variables` in the command [`az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create):

> A list of environment variables for the container. Space-separated
>   values in 'key=value' format.

It requires the value of a list. So you can read from the file to create a list and then use the list as the value of the parameter `--environment-variables` in the create command.